# ¿Por qué Bash me da el error "se esperaba una expresión entera"?

Tags: linux, bash, variables, shell-script

Tengo este código en "ej3.sh":

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 -gt $2 ] ; then
        cont=$2
        while [ $cont -le $1 ]  # <-- línea que da error
        do
                cont=$cont+1
                echo $cont
        done
else
        echo 'el primer argmento NO es mayor que el segundo'
fi
```

Lo intento ejecutar con `bash ej3.sh 9 4` y obtengo el siguiente error:

```
1+2
ej3: línea 4: [: 1+2: se esperaba una expresión entera
```

La idea es que me muestre una lista de números creciente comprendida entre el segundo parámetro y el primero, pero algo me está fallando en la sintaxis

Comment: Hay unos cuantos errores conceptuales que convendría mirar antes de nada. Sugiero pegar el código en https://www.shellcheck.net, que lo explica muy bien. La clave está en que si no pasas los dos parámetros, `[ $1 -gt $2 ]` queda cojo. De ahí que valga la pena poner siempre comillas dobles y validar el contenido previamente.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Lo estoy ejecutando como ` bash ej3 9 4`, ¡gracias por tus aportaciones! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voy a suponer que corres tu programa de maneras como:

```
$ ./programa 4 2 
$ bash ./programa 4 2
```

Una cosa es un **incremento** y otra cosa es una **concatenación**. Ambas pueden confundir al principio en Bash.

Para el **incremento**, se puede utilizar una característica [llamada *arithmetic expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html); que me parece que es lo que buscas.

En ese sentido, basta con que a la variable `cont`, para incrementarla, la escribas como:

```
((cont++))  # Así, sin asignar, la variable también queda incrementada
# O una versión más larga:
cont=$((cont+1))
# En lugar de:
cont=$cont+1
```

Lo que has estado haciendo es una **concatenación**. Puesto que en Bash, poner una cosa al lado de otra, es un simple concatenar:

```
var=1+1       # Es la cadena "1+1"
var=$((1+1))  # Es el número 2
```

Ya te imaginarás que a los operadores sobre enteros (`-eq`, `-le`, `-lt`, etc) no les parece hacer operaciones sobre cadenas, por lo que cuando dices `while [ $cont -le $1 ]` le estás pasando `while [ 1+2 -le 2 ]`, que es algo que no puede procesar porque el operando de la izquierda no es un entero. Y ahí es donde salta y te da el error "se esperaba una expresión entera".

Comment: Por las comillas? También. Yo me enfoqué en la parte de la cuarta línea; cuando hace la comparación de la nueva cadena con el entero.

Comment: Yo entiendo que lo ejecuta algo así: `./programa 3 2`, por ejemplo. Entonces pasa el primer `if` y la primera pasada del `while`; pero no las siguientes porque dentro del `while` queda vuelto un string de la forma `x+y`.

Comment: @Cuauhtli Efectivamente, estaba concatenando y lo que intentaba era incrementar. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'. Creo que tengo que aclarar la forma de ejecución eso en mi respuesta. Porque también me causó confusión.